# Workflow for current version of excel document

Tags: versioning, workflow-variable

I have an excel document I am maintaining on SP, and at-least once a week this document needs to be mailed to several people. Not all are SharePoint enthusiast so I need to maintain their requirements of:

- a document management tab with version history (different from SP versioning)
- the current version and date in the file-name that is sent

I like to keep the name of this file clean(no version or date) on SP and when I need to send it out, initiate some workflow that gets the current version from the document management tab in excel and saves this together with the current date in the filename that I send out. The file that I mail would then look like for example: `"excelfilename 26112015 v4.0.xlsx"`

Its a while back that I messed with SharePoint designer and before I start doing so again I thought I give here a try. Anyone?